# How to filter GCP stackdriver logs by timestamp from python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to get GCP stackdriver logs from python module.
I can filter logs from request_id and user

but when I'm trying to get logs between two time periods it gives my error.

```
import json
import sys
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud.logging import DESCENDING
from google.cloud import bigquery

#stackdriver client object
logging_client = logging.Client()

FILTER="logName:projects/cognitedata-europe-west1-1/logs/stdout AND timestamp>="+sys.argv[3]
results_iterator = logging_client.list_entries(filter_=FILTER,projects=PROJECT_IDS,order_by=DESCENDING,page_size=1000)
```

I use following pattens to provide time.

```
timestamp:sys.argv[3]
```

```
timestamp=sys.argv[3]
```

```
timestamp>sys.argv[3]
```

```
timestamp>=sys.argv[3]
```

But noting solves my issue.

I have input time for sys.argv[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7eiV.png) as "2019-09-28T03:28:04.189Z"

My requirement is to filter data from the timestamp
[image]

But in GCP stack driver logger UI it gives results for both

```
timestamp:"2019-09-28T03:28:04.189Z"
```

[image]

and

```
timestamp>="2019-09-28T03:28:04.189Z" AND timestamp<="2019-09-28T03:30:39.189Z"
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect (!) you need to escape the timestamp that you provide. You're providing `FILTER="timestamp>=2019-09-28T03:28:04.189Z` (NB the value is not quoted) but you want `FILTER="timestamp>=2019-09-28T03:28:04.189Z"`. You want: `...AND timestamp>=\""+sys.argv[3]\""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by DazWilkin in the comments, you need to include the double quotes in the filter as well.
You can do something like:

```
FILTER="logName:projects/cognitedata-europe-west1-1/logs/stdout AND timestamp>=" + "\"" + sys.argv[3] + "\""
```

If the above looks too complicated to read, you can use the combination of Python's single and double quoted strings which would look something like below:

```
FILTER='logName:projects/cognitedata-europe-west1-1/logs/stdout AND timestamp>=' + '\"' + sys.argv[3] + '\"'
```

NOTE: Backward slashes(\) are being used to escape the double quotes(").